# Pyinstaller is using python2.7 instead of 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have pyinstaller installed on both pythons, how do i use only python3?

I have tried:

```
pyinstaller3
```

however, that says no command is found. I also tried uninstalled pyinstaller from 2.7 but then it says pyintaller isn't found. How do I run pyinstaller for python3?

when I do:

```
pip3 install pyinstaller
```

i get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pyinstaller)
```

why is it defaulting to 2.7?? How do i switch it?

Comment: I had a similar problem with pip. I solved it using `python3 -m pip ...` instead of `pip3`. I'm not sure if it'll work with pyinstaller, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: @Rawing It installed it but still saying no module found when I try and run python3 -m pyinstaller my_file.py

Comment: see if `pyinstaller` is installed using the correct pip - you can see the installed packages via `python3 -m pip freeze`.